# R: Mean of subsets of dataframe on both row and column labels

Tags: r, subset, mean

Let's say I have:

```
set.seed(42) 
d = data.frame(replicate(6,rnorm(10)))
col_labels = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c")
row_labels = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
```

I now want to calculate the mean value of a subset of `d` corresponding to each combination of `col_labels` and `row_labels`, ie:

```
s = subset(d, row_labels==1, select=col_labels=="a")
s_mean = mean(as.matrix(s))
```

In the end, I would like a dataframe, with rows corresponding to `row_labels` and columns corresponding to `col_labels` and values the mean value of the subset. How do I do this without a large number of for-loops?

Comment: Can you show us your desired result?  You have three answers and it's hard to tell if any/all are what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
res <- lapply(split.default(d, col_labels), FUN=by, INDICES=list(row_labels), function(x) mean(unlist(x)))
do.call(rbind, res)
#          1       2       3       4
# a  0.56201  0.1563  0.4393 -0.3193
# b -0.01075  0.7515 -0.7973 -0.8620
# c  0.28615 -0.3406  0.1443 -0.1583
```

Comment: Great thanks! This is elegant, and returns the data as a matrix, rather than just a list of combinations.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
set.seed(42) 
d <- data.frame(replicate(6,rnorm(10)))
indx <- expand.grid(unique(row_labels), unique(col_labels))
val1 <- apply(indx, 1, function(x) 
         mean(as.matrix(subset(d, row_labels==x[1], select=col_labels==x[2]))))
val1
#[1]  0.56200717  0.15625521  0.43927374 -0.31929307 -0.01074557  0.75147423
#[7] -0.79730155 -0.86200887  0.28615306 -0.34058148  0.14431610 -0.15834522
```

Or

```
 fun1 <- function(x,y) mean(as.matrix(subset(d, row_labels==x, select=col_labels==y)))
 mapply(fun1, indx[,1], indx[,2])
 #[1]  0.56200717  0.15625521  0.43927374 -0.31929307 -0.01074557  0.75147423
 #[7] -0.79730155 -0.86200887  0.28615306 -0.34058148  0.14431610 -0.15834522
```

Or using `outer`

```
  outer(unique(row_labels), unique(col_labels), Vectorize(fun1))
  #         [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
  #[1,]  0.5620072 -0.01074557  0.2861531
  #[2,]  0.1562552  0.75147423 -0.3405815
  #[3,]  0.4392737 -0.79730155  0.1443161
  #[4,] -0.3192931 -0.86200887 -0.1583452
```

cbind the `indx` and `val`

```
 res <- cbind(indx, val1)
 head(res,3)
 #Var1 Var2      val1
 #1    1    a 0.5620072
 #2    2    a 0.1562552
 #3    3    a 0.4392737

 mean(as.matrix(subset(d, row_labels==1, select=col_labels=="a")))
  #[1] 0.5620072
 mean(as.matrix(subset(d, row_labels==2, select=col_labels=="a")))
 #[1] 0.1562552
```

#### Update

You can also change the formatting

```
 res1 <-  outer(unique(row_labels), unique(col_labels), Vectorize(fun1))
 dimnames(res1) <- list(unique(row_labels), unique(col_labels))
 res1
 #          a           b          c
 #1  0.5620072 -0.01074557  0.2861531
 #2  0.1562552  0.75147423 -0.3405815
 #3  0.4392737 -0.79730155  0.1443161
 #4 -0.3192931 -0.86200887 -0.1583452
```

Or you could use `reshape2`

```
 library(reshape2)
 acast(res, Var1~Var2, value.var="val1")
#         a           b          c
#1  0.5620072 -0.01074557  0.2861531
#2  0.1562552  0.75147423 -0.3405815
#3  0.4392737 -0.79730155  0.1443161
#4 -0.3192931 -0.86200887 -0.1583452
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to change the data to long format. You should consider why you imported the data in this format, and better ways of cleaning it.

Firstly, set the column names

```
colnames(d) <- col_labels
```

Secondly, you cannot have duplicate rownames, so you can't simply do rownames(d) <- row_labels.

Instead, we're going to have to split them up another way. You could use

```
split(d, rowlabels)
```

Now we're going to get it all into long format. The melt function in the package reshape2 is commonly used for this.

```
require(reshape2)
dMelt <- melt(split(d, row_labels))
```

Now look at dMelt. Is there any reason you couldn't have organised the data in this way?

In order to find the subsetted means, use the function aggregate()

```
aggregate(dMelt$value, FUN=mean, by=list(dMelt$variable, dMelt$L1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here an option using `data.table`. It should be very fast and with any loop

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
set.seed(42) 
merge(
setkey(data.table(variable=colnames(d),x=col_labels),variable),
setkey(melt(setDT(d)[,row:=row_labels,],id.vars="row"),variable))[
  ,mean(value),c("row","x")]

   row x          V1
 1:   1 a  0.56200717
 2:   2 a  0.15625521
 3:   3 a  0.43927374
 4:   4 a -0.31929307
 5:   1 b -0.01074557
 6:   2 b  0.75147423
 7:   3 b -0.79730155
 8:   4 b -0.86200887
 9:   1 c  0.28615306
10:   2 c -0.34058148
11:   3 c  0.14431610
12:   4 c -0.15834522
```

The idea is to :

1. put the d data.frame in the long format after adding row labels as a row
2. merge it with another data table to to have correspondence between previous column names and your repeated column names
3. Compute the mean by group of row and x ( resulted from the merge)